# Apache-Kafka-Connect , Confluent-HDFS-Connector , Unknown-magic-byte

Tags: java, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have use Confluent HDFS Connector for moving data from Kafka topics to HDFS log file. But when I run these commands:

> ./bin/connect-standalone
>   etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties \
>   etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties

I am taking follow error. How can i solve this problem. What is the reason of that ?

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
>   Error deserializing Avro message for id -1 Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic
>   byte! [2017-06-03 13:44:41,895] ERROR Task is being killed and will
>   not recover until manually restarted
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:142)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you are trying to read data read the connector and have set `key.converter` and `value.converter` to be the `AvroConverter` but your input topic has data that was not serialized by the same `AvroSerializer` that uses the schema registry.

You have to match your converter to the input data. In other words, use a serializer that can deserialize the input data.

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: Put org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter as the key.converter and value.converter in etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties instead of the current values in that file.

Comment: Thank you but that is not enough dawsaw . 

Confluent move .avro file but that .avro file just is including avro schema. Not data. However kafka topic has lots of data.   

hadoop jar /home/hadoop/avro-tools-1.7.7.jar getmeta /topics/kafka_log_test/partition=0/kafka_log_test+0+0000000018+0000000020.avro

>the result of this command:

avro.schema     {"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}],"connect.version":1,"connect.name":"myrecord"}


How can i send .avro file with data.

Comment: If you're just wanting the data exactly as it is in the topic to be moved to hdfs then consider using the bytearrayconverter https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-128%3A+Add+ByteArrayConverter+for+Kafka+Connect it's merged to 0.11 which is in the release candidate phase. Otherwise you have to use the AvroConverter which means the data needs to be produced to Kafka using the schema registry. It looks like this isn't what you are doing currently so I'd say just use that bytearrayconverter and deal with any bad records on the hdfs side.